# .NET Reflection: how do I loop through an object that is an array type?

Tags: c#, .net, reflection

I've got a method that returns an array, the type of which I have stored in a Type object further up. The code I have for this is thus:

```
Type StoryType = Type.GetType("my.ns.Story");
Type StoryTypeArray = Type.GetType("my.ns.Story[]");

object stories = SomeMethodInfo.Invoke(BigFatObject,some_params);
```

In this example, I know stories is of type `StoryTypeArray`, and what I really want to do is something like:

```
foreach (Story instance in stories) { ... }
```

However, I can't figure out how to turn the object `stories` into something I can loop through and pull data out of.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It's not clear from your question if the `Story` type is actually known to you at compile time. If it is, the solution is trivial; just cast `stores` to `Story[]` and iterate over it as usual:

```
foreach(Story instance in (Story[])stories) { ... }
```

This also means that `StoryType` can be written as `typeof(Story)` and `StoryTypeArray` can be written as `typeof(StoryTypeArray[])` instead of using the less-safe `Type.GetType` that you're using.

If the type is not actually known to you at compile time, then you won't be able to write `foreach(Story instance...`, since that won't be a valid type. If you just want to iterate over the array, then you can do this:

```
foreach(object item in (Array)stories) { ... }
```

Comment: +1 - I would also suggest doing a cast to `IEnumerable` and then trying to use the data, ex: `stories as IEnumerable`

Comment: Apologies, should have been clearer - the type isn't known at compiletime, otherwise casting would have been easy! I didn't know you could cast as a generic array and loop through that. Will give that a go.

Comment: @growse: As @Tejs suggests, you could also cast it to `System.Collections.IEnumerable`, since all arrays implement that and it'll get you the bare minimum of what you need to iterate over it.

Answer (score 1):

If for some reasons you've got to do this through reflection, here is the solution:

```
a.GetType().GetMethod("Get").Invoke(a, new object[]{0})
```